# How to fix relaunch current activity when two tables of realtime database are changed

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 tables in realtime database(table User and table Product). First I added data to Product table then I updated data of User table. After updating User table, current activity relaunches(restarts)

```
  DatabaseReference databaseReference;
FirebaseDatabase products;
DatabaseReference users;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    products = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Product");
    users = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Product product new Product("Android");

            products.push().setValue(product)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            users.child("123").child("summa").setValue("newValue");

                        }
                    });
        }

    });
}
```

All data are saved correctly.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that indicates the launch of a new activity. Please add the related code to your question.